How to send list of images to server in Flutter web using Dio package
I am trying to send List of Images to the server and get reference to them in Flutter web  by using Dio package.
Please check my code and let me know where I am doing wrong. Or if you have best solution please post here. Even if you have a solution with htttp package as well. Thank you in advance.
Future<void> uploadPhotos(String _jwtToken, BuildContext context) async {
 AppartDetailsListener profileDetailsListener =
  Provider.of<AppartDetailsListener>(context, listen: false);
try {
Dio dio = Dio();
FormData formData = FormData();
for (int i = 0; i < profileDetailsListener.getXfileList.length; i++) {
  String fileName = 'photo_$i.jpg';
  html.File htmlFile = html.File(
      await profileDetailsListener.getXfileList[i].readAsBytes(), fileName);

  final reader = html.FileReader();
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(htmlFile);

  await reader.onLoadEnd.first;
  final Uint8List bytes = reader.result as Uint8List;

  formData.files.add(MapEntry(
    'photos',
    MultipartFile.fromBytes(bytes, filename: fileName),
  ));
}
Response response = await dio.post(
  'API',
  data: formData,
  options: Options(
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $_jwtToken',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
  ),
);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  List<String> photoReferences = List<String>.from(response.data);

  print('Photo references: $photoReferences');
} else {
  print('Failed to upload images. Status code: ${response.statusCode}');
}
} catch (e) {
print('Error uploading images: $e');
}
}

I am getting code 200 but no referance to the list of images.
